# How to iterate through nested items in Ansible

Tags: arrays, loops, ansible

I'm not sure if i'm taking the correct way but i have the next problem.

I need a simple task like:

```
  - name: Copying files
    template:
      src: "{{ item[1] }}.j2"
      dest: "{{ path }}/{{ item[0] }}/{{ item[1] }}"
    with_nested:
      - [ 'env1' , 'env2' ]
      - [ 'file1' , 'file2']
```

Actual results:

```
/path/env1/file1
/path/env1/file2
```

```
/path/env2/file1
/path/env2/file2
```

Expected results:

```
/path/env1/file1
/path/env2/file2
```

I just need that file1 generate template in directory env1 and the file2 generate template in env2.
I can't do it with a simple 'with_items' because i hace 2 items to iterate, the name of the directory and the name of the file.

I'm sure that there is a way to do that correctly..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use [zip](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-together) filter. The play below

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    list1: [ 'env1' , 'env2' ]
    list2: [ 'file1' , 'file2']
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "/path/{{ item.0 }}/{{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ list1|zip(list2)|list }}"
```

gives (grep msg):

```
    "msg": "/path/env1/file1"
    "msg": "/path/env2/file2"
```

Comment: But i have not defined these vars and i wouldn't like define it.. There is another way?

Comment: Sure, do it as you like and put the lists in place of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

you can try following to get expected results :

```
  - name: Copying files
    template:
      src: "{{ item[1] }}.j2"
      dest: "{{ path }}/{{ item[0] }}/{{ item[1] }}"
    with_together:
      - [ 'env1' , 'env2' ]
      - [ 'file1' , 'file2']
```

[with_together](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/together.html) explanation